How to simply iterate with params (from a JSON input) over an existing jenkins pipeline with sequential stages
I've got an existing jenkins pipeline with almost 10 stages with a lot of code, and now i need to iterate bases ob new parameters from a json in place of a single string parameter ?
The purpose is to keep the original structure and just adding an enter stage to get the stage list and loop over the stages list.

Does your pipeline generate any stages dynamically? Because, you know, it could... Or is it strictly declarative?

Finaly i used a second job to manage the loop from parameters, and call the original job with static stages (declarative pipeline) by using the code : downstreamJob = build job: 'my job', parameters: [ string(name: 'Environnement', value: "${var1}"), string(name: 'var2', value: "${name}") ]
